# One Outlet in Circuit Briefly Losing Power

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit

There is a 20 amp circuit in my house which includes 5 outlets: 2 in the kitchen (on the wall towards the floor, no appliances plugged in, just a small water fountain for the cat) and 3 in the office. One of the outlets in the office has a power strip attached with a laptop dock, 2 computer monitors, and an internet router plugged in.

Here’s the problem we’re having: when we plug something into the first outlet in the circuit, which is in the kitchen, the outlet in the office momentarily loses power. This only lasts about 30 seconds and then the power is back. The circuit doesn’t trip or anything like that. None of the other outlets are affected, we have checked and they all have power during this event.

I checked and the wires are 12 gauge. It is a 20 amp circuit with 20 amp outlets. I checked all the outlets and the wires are secure.

Comment: Are the wires attached to the outlets using side-screws or backstabs?

Comment: Does this interruption in the power at the office receptacle occur if you plug something into the kitchen receptacle but do not draw any power (don't turn on whatever is plugged in), that is, is it just the mechanical disturbance to the receptacle that causes the interruption?